# Adding react-router history to dependency array of useEffect necessary?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, use-effect

I have a component with a useEffect like this:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Component = ({ id }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(async () => {
    await asyncFetchData(id);
    history.push("/homepage");
  }, [history]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>Click</Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

I'm wondering if it's necessary to put the `history` from `react-router-dom` in the dependency array of the `useEffect`. Does anyone know if it's needed or not?

Comment: It is not needed, however it may trigger lint issues.
Leaving it in is totally safe also.
The only reason you would possibly need it is if you were swapping out the history object from the app component

Comment: What is the output you need to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `history` object to the dependency array of the `useEffect` or `useCallback` hook does not make any difference in renders.

The `history` object's reference stays the same within the component. The object will be mutated only on the navigation to a different route, in which case a different component will be rendered.

This can be considered as a false positive warning thrown by ESlint. It is suggested to keep the code cleaner and more readable by not adding it to the dependency array of the `useEffect` or `useCallback` hook. To remove the warning you may ignore it using the comment `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` or let it be.